# How should I handle Perl 6 $*ARGFILES that can't be read by lines()?

Tags: io, raku

I'm playing around with `lines` which reads lines from the files you specify on the command line:

```
for lines() { put $_ }
```

If it can't read one of the filenames it throws `X::AdHoc` (one day maybe it will have better exception types so we can grab the filename with a `.path` method). Fine, so catch that:

```
try {
CATCH { default { put .^name } }
for lines() { put $_ }
}
```

So this catches the `X::AdHoc` error but that's it. The `try` block is done at that point. It can't `.resume` and try the next file:

```
try {
CATCH { default { put .^name; .resume } }  # Nope
for lines() { put $_ }
}
```

Back in Perl 5 land you get a warning about the bad filename and the program moves on to the next thing.

I could filter `@*ARGS` first then reconstruct `$*ARGFILES` if there are some arguments:

```
$*ARGFILES = IO::CatHandle.new:  
    @*ARGS.grep( { $^a.IO.e and $^a.IO.r } ) if +@*ARGS;

for lines() { put $_ }
```

That works although it silently ignores bad files. I could handle that but it's a bit tedious to handle the argument list myself, including `-` for standard input as a filename and the default with no arguments:

```
my $code := { put $_ };

@*ARGS = '-' unless +@*ARGS;
for @*ARGS -> $arg {
    given $arg {
        when '-'     { $code.($_) for $*IN.lines(); next }
        when ! .IO.e { note "$_ does not exist";    next }
        when ! .IO.r { note "$_ is not readable";   next }
        default      { $code.($_) for $arg.IO.lines() }
        }
    }
```

But that's a lot of work. Is there a simpler way to handle this?

Comment: I think the bug here is really a. that it is not a typed exception with a `.path` and b. that it is not resumable.  Please create a GH issue / RT ticket for this.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen FWIW: looking at the spec, we don't guarantee `.resume`ability of Exceptions thrown by core at all; not to mention guaranteeing that .resuming would produce any meaningful behaviour (such as re-trying with the next handle). IMO, we shouldn't just start supporting that on a whim and should instead look at whether that can be supported as a general pattern across the entire core. (FWIW making IO::CatHandle.next-handle throw X::AdHoc directly and resuming it explodes after resuming in some secondary place with "Something went wrong in (AdHoc)")

Answer (score 5):

To warn on bad open and move on, you could use something like this:

```
$*ARGFILES does role { method next-handle { loop {
    try return self.IO::CatHandle::next-handle;
    warn "WARNING: $!.message"
}}}

.say for lines
```

Simply [mixing in a role](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/does) that makes the [IO::CatHandle.next-handle](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::CatHandle#method_next-handle) method re-try getting next handle. (you can also use [`but` operator](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/does) to mixin on a copy instead).

---

> If it can't read one of the filenames it throws X::AdHoc

The `X::AdHoc` is from `.open` call; there's a [somewhat moldy PR to make those exceptions typed](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/894), so once that's fixed, `IO::CatHandle` would throw typed exceptions as well.

> It can't .resume

Yeah, you can only resume from a `CATCH` block that caught it, but in this case it's caught inside `.open` call and is made into a `Failure`, which is then received by `IO::CatHandle.next-handle` and its `.exception` is re-`.throw`n.

However, even if it were resumable here, it'd simply resume into a path where exception was thrown, not re-try with another handle. It wouldn't help. (I looked into making it resumable, but that adds vagueness to `on-switch` and I'm not comfortable speccing that resuming `Exception`s from certain places must be able to meaningfully continue—we currently don't offer such a guarantee for any place in core).

> including `-` for standard input as a filename

Note that that special meaning is [going away in 6.d language](https://github.com/perl6/6.d-prep/blob/master/TODO/FEATURES.md#de-magicalize---in-iohandleopen) as far as `IO::Handle.open` (and by extension `IO::CatHandle.new`) goes. It might get special treatment in `IO::ArgFiles`, but I've not seen that proposed.

---

> Back in Perl 5 land you get a warning about the bad filename and the program moves on to the next thing.

In Perl 6, it's implemented as a generalized `IO::CatHandle` type users can use for anything, not just file arguments, so warning and moving on by default feels too lax to me.

`IO::ArgFiles` could be special-cased to offer such behaviour. Personally, I'm against special casing stuff all over the place and I think that is the biggest flaw in Perl 5, but you could [open an Issue proposing that](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/new) and see if anyone backs it.

Comment: I think it should be given as part of the sequence, and not a thrown error. Then it could be as simple as calling `next` if that error shows up in the Seq.

Comment: @BradGilbert the `Seq` from `lines`? That would violate interchangeability of (read-only) IO::Handle and IO::CatHandle and wouldn't help with other methods, such as `.read` or `.slurp`.

Comment: Having it throw a file not found error after it has been successfully reading from the "file" also violates interchangeability. The way it works now, it could appear to be easier to reimplement the algorithm in user code than to use the built-in one; perhaps leading to many poorly written re-implementations by new Perl 6 programmers. Right now you basically have to know how it is implemented to work around it. There are many ways it isn't interchangeable, for example try writing to it. We should be aiming for usefully interchangeable. (There could be a better way than I propose, I accept that)

Comment: @BradGilbert I don't see what you proposed solving anything at all. The proposal merely creates surprising behaviour for users, creates hidden (e.g. `my @lines = lines` now has unblown Failures in it), adds overhead from having to check each line for errors, and solves absolutely nothing for all the other reading methods.

Comment: If it returns them inline you could at least do `.grep(&defined)` if you don't care about failures. If you do care about failures, but you want to be able to continue; currently you can't really do so in a clean way.

Comment: @BradGilbert that still has the overhead of testing each line, or even **each word** for the `.words` method. And anyone who forgets to do it or doesn't know it has to be done will have bugs in their code.

Once [RT#132885](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132885#ticket-history) is fixed, users can stick a `CATCH` with `.next-handle` in it, with no overhead, no bugs, and the same—but now optional—code.