# Dealing with invalid filehandles (and maybe other invalid objects too)

Tags: exception, io, raku

As indicated by Tom Browder in [this issue](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2666), the [`$*ARGFILES` dynamic variable](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2AARGFILES) might contain invalid filehandles if any of the files mentioned in the command line is not present.

```
for $*ARGFILES.handles -> $fh {
    say $fh;
}
```

will fail with and `X::AdHoc` exception (this should probably be improved too):

```
Failed to open file /home/jmerelo/Code/perl6/my-perl6-examples/args/no-file: No such file or directory
```

The problem will occur as soon as the invalid filehandle is used for  anything. Would there be a way of checking if the filehandle is valid before incurring in an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** I thought Liz had it nailed but it seems like there's a bug or perhaps Ugh.

## A bug?

It looks like whenever the [`IO::CatHandle` class's `.handles` method](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::CatHandle#method_handles) reaches a handle that ought by rights produce a `Failure` (delaying any exception throw) it instead immediately throws an exception (perhaps the very one that would work if it were just delayed or perhaps something broken).

This seems either wrong or very wrong.

## Ugh

See [the exchange between Zoffix and Brad Gilbert and Zoffix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48876495/1077672) to the question [How should I handle Perl 6 $*ARGFILES that can't be read by lines()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865412/how-should-i-handle-perl-6-argfiles-that-cant-be-read-by-lines)

Also:

- https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1313
- https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=argfiles&type=Issues
- https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=cathandle&type=Issues

## A potential workaround is currently another bug?

In discussing ["Implement handler for failed open on `IO::CatHandle"`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1543) Zoffix++ closed it with this code as a solution:

```
.say for ($*ARGFILES but role {
    method next-handle {
        loop {try return self.IO::CatHandle::next-handle}
    }
})
```

I see that tbrowder has reopened this issue as part of the related issue this SO is about saying:

> If this works, it would at least be a usable example for the `$*ARGFILES` var in the docs.

But when I run it in `6.d` (and see similar results for a `6.c`), with or without valid input, I get:

```
say not yet implemented
```

(similar if I `.put` or whatever).

This is nuts and suggests something gutsy is getting messed up.

I've searched rt and gh/rakudo issues for "not yet implemented" and see no relevant matches.

## Another workaround?

Zoffix clearly intended their code as a permanent solution, not merely a workaround. But it unfortunately doesn't seem to work at all for now.

The best I've come up with so far:

```
try {$*ARGFILES} andthen say $_    # $_ is a defined ArgFiles instance
                 orelse  say $!;   # $! is an error encountered inside the `try`
```

Perhaps this works as a black-and-white it either all works or none of it does solution. (Though I'm not convinced it's even that.)

## What the doc has to say about `$*ARGFILES`

[`$*ARGFILES`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#index-entry-%24%2AARGFILES) says it is an instance of

[`IO::ArgFiles`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::ArgFiles) which is doc'd as a class which

> exists for backwards compatibility reasons and provides no methods.

And

> All the functionality is inherited from

[`IO::CatHandle`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::CatHandle) which is subtitled as

> Use multiple IO handles as if they were one

and doc'd as a class that `is`

[`IO::Handle`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Handle) which is subtitled as

> Opened file or stream

and doc'd as a class that doesn't inherit from any other class (so defaults to inheriting from `Any`) or do any role.

So, `$*ARGFILES` is (exactly functionally the same as) a `IO::CatHandle` object which is (a superset of the functionality of) an `IO::Handle` object, specifically:

> The `IO::CatHandle` class provides a means to create an `IO::Handle` that seamlessly gathers input from multiple `IO::Handle` and `IO::Pipe` sources. All of `IO::Handle`'s methods are implemented, and while attempt to use write methods will (currently) throw an exception, an `IO::CatHandle` is usable anywhere a read-only `IO::Handle` can be used.

## Exploring [the code for `IO::CatHandle`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/IO/CatHandle.pm6)

(To be filled in later?)

Comment: $*ARGFILES is OK, it's $*ARGFILES.handles the one that raises the error. But try might be a good approach in that case.

Comment: Thanks. I got spectacularly off track twice (there's another deleted answer unrelated to this one that I will likely never reveal. :)). Anyhoo, answer rewritten. It's not yet making sense to me that you've accepted this answer. Are you sure my workaround works for you or Tom?

Comment: You don't have to reveal it. If a person has enough reputation points they can still read it. [`.next-handle` throws the Failure as soon as it sees it](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/df96fa0f34075acbe110c7d8e944a1332f1f11eb/src/core/IO/CatHandle.pm6#L73-L79)

Comment: @BradGilbert Thx for headsup about reveal. Yeah, the code you linked is clearly the problem. And you and Zoffix have discussed it b4 per the exchange I linked on the SO posted by bdfoy, right? (I'm trying to properly understand the pros and cons of Zoffix's view vs yours about it.) Do the bugs listed by the links I included in the **Ugh** section of my answer adequately cover the problem already or do you think we need another issue posted? In the meantime, have you got any clue about the bizarre `not yet implemented` message in the **A potential workaround is currently another bug?** section?

Comment: As far as I can fathom, removing that `.throw` would not cause any previously working code to suddenly fail. It should make it so that Zoffix's code above works, It should make it so that lizmat's code also works. The thing is everyone is writing code with the expectation that it is a Failure not an Exception. So why not make it so?

Answer (score 8):

You can check if something is a `Failure` by checking for truthiness or definedness **without** the `Failure` throwing:

```
for $*ARGFILES.handles -> $fh {
    say $fh if $fh;  # check truthiness
    .say with $fh;   # check definedness + topicalization
}
```

If you still want to throw the `Exception` that the `Failure` encompasses, then you can just `.throw` it.

Comment: Still the same problem, it's thrown at the `if $fh` level. The second one is weirder, since it says "Bad file descriptor".

Comment: Hi @jjmerelo and liz. An exception is getting thrown inside the `.handles`. It doesn't get as far as doing the `-> $fh` binding let alone entering the block and doing the `if` statement. I would hope that it's just a tweak somewhere in `IO::CatHandle` to return a `Failure` instead of throwing. But even if that is fixed, see my answer for the solution Zoffix proposed which is strange in that A) they suggested it (why not just the `for` loop?) and B) it has a bizarre bug.

Comment: The problem is that the `.handles` iterator calls `.next-handle` which [unconditionally throws the Failure](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/df96fa0f34075acbe110c7d8e944a1332f1f11eb/src/core/IO/CatHandle.pm6#L73-L79).